# IP tables routing connected teamspeak clients

Tags: networking, server, iptables, teamspeak

On a hosted ubuntu server VPS I host a teamspeak server. Is there anyway to use IPTables to force a connected client to join a different server by forwarding them to the IP?

For example

Teamspeak Server 1 ---> Teamspeak server 2 (Hosted on a second VPS)

I've already tried using the commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s [IP] -j DNAT --to [IP2]
```

and

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s [IP] -d [IP2] -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Hey, did you eventually find a way to do it?

Comment: Yeah, we just used iptables to cause him to loose connection and then removed the rule, that connected him to the other server